# Iterating day-by-day and removing entries from a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm a newbie in `MongoDB` so this may sound like a simple question, but I am unable to make this seemingly simple query work:

```
var startDate = Date.UTC(2018, 4, 1);
var endDate = Date.UTC(2018, 4, 30)
while(startDate < endDate){
  print(startDate);
  db.<colln>.remove(
    { 'time_bucket': { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: startDate } } },
    { 'URL':/https:\/\/abc.com/}
    )
    startDate = startDate +  86400000
}
```

I'm trying to delete all the entries that match `abc.com`. I get the count first before running the above query:

```
db.<colln>.find({'time_bucket':'2018-04-month', 'URL':/https:\/\/abc.com/}).count()
```

This is returning a count, so the URL pattern is working. But I am unable to delete the records, as the count comes in the same before and after running the `remove` query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for a loop, you can do it like this:

```
db.<colln>.deleteMany( {
   time_bucket: {
      $gte: new Date.UTC(2018, 4, 1), 
      $lt: new Date.UTC(2018, 4, 30)
   },
   URL: /https:\/\/abc.com/
} )
```

Whenever you work wit date/time values, I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. Could be like this:

```
db.<colln>.deleteMany( {
   time_bucket: {
      $gte: moment.utc("2018-04-01").startOf('month').toDate(), 
      $lte: moment.utc("2018-04-01").endOf('month').toDate()
   },
   URL: /https:\/\/abc.com/
} )
```

In order to run it in a loop (not tested):

```
var d =  moment.utc("2018-04-01").startOf('month');
while ( d.isBefore(d.endOf('month')) ) {
    db.<colln>.deleteMany( {
       time_bucket: {
          $gte: d.startOf('day')toDate(), 
          $lte: d.endOf('day').toDate()
       },
       URL: /https:\/\/abc.com/
    } );
    d.add(1, 'day');
}
```

Comment: I tried the above earlier,  but the collection is too large and it doesn't work. It needs to be done on a day-by-day basis. Would you have any other ideas on how to make it day-by-day?

Comment: Most likely running it in a loop will not make it faster. Do you have an index on `time_bucket`? Also the regexp could make the operation slower, not the date field. I added a solution with a loop, however I don't expect much difference.